# Explicit self-references with no type / difference with ''this''

Tags: scala, self-type

I understand the use for [explicitly typed self-references](http://www.scala-lang.org/node/124):

```
trait T {
  self : T2 =>
  ...
}
```

In the body, `self` is an alias for `this` but has the more precise type `T with T2`.

Now, I've seen this in code:

```
trait T {
  self =>
  ...
}
```

That is, an explicit self reference with no additional type information. In this configuration, is there any situation in which `self` is not just an alias for `this`?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

It is an alias for `this`.

Your first example is useful for ensuring that the trait has been mixed in to an appropriate type, and makes those methods available.

The second example is useful when you have inner classes with naming conflicts, to make the outer scope visible. For example:

```
trait U {
  self =>
  val name = "outer"
  val b = new AnyRef {
    val name = "inner"
    println(name)
    println(this.name)
    println(self.name)
  }
}
```

Then `new AnyRef with U` prints

```
inner
inner
outer
```

"self" is not a special keyword - you can use "bananas =>" or whatever you like, but it's often used by convention.

This crops up quite a bit in Swing, where you make a lot on inner classes (textboxes within scrollpanes, etc), which usually have many methods with the same names as the outer classes.

Comment: Good points, thanks. So it's equivalent to the longer form `U.this.name` in this case, I guess.

Answer (score 10):

In that case `self` is a another way of saying `this`.

If you happen to have an inner class, however, `this` inside the inner class would be the inner class, and `self` would be the container class.

That's the only difference AFAIK

Comment: And probably its purpose.