# What does this self-type mean?

Tags: scala

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Scala this aliasing and self type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10836905/scala-this-aliasing-and-self-type)

I come across this piece of code.

```
abstract class Tagged(private var t: Int) { self =>
...
}
```

I know that the following means a dependency relationship of Tagged and B, but could not understand the above one, could anyone explain the difference ? Thanks

```
abstract class Tagged(private var t: Int) { self:B  =>
...
}
```

Comment: Nit: I would write the latter as `self: B`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first form introduces an alias for `this`; the second form constrains the self-type.

For example, in scala.Enumeration, `thisenum` is used as an alias for `Enumeration.this` from nested classes.  In the change log appendix to the spec, it says the alias is designed as replacement syntax.

Comment: I would also like to add that aliasing `this` is helpful when you have nested classes and you want to access the `this` of the outer-class from the inner-class.

Comment: Yes, that would be the case with Enumeration, hence an example.