# Understanding real cake pattern code with self and this references

Tags: scala, types, cake-pattern, singleton-type, refinement-type

I have recently learnt about cake pattern and the differences between the uses of `self =>` and `self:T =>` (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8073263/explicit-self-references-with-no-type-difference-with-this)). The difference between these technicalities and real Scala code as [remarked here](http://marcus-christie.blogspot.com/2014/03/scala-understanding-self-type.html) continue to create me problems. For instance, see the following code snippet taken from the [Inox project](https://github.com/epfl-lara/inox/blob/master/src/main/scala/inox/ast/Trees.scala):

```
trait Trees
  extends Expressions
     with Constructors
     with Extractors
     with Types
     with Definitions
     with Printers
     with TreeOps { self =>

     ...

     val interpolator: Interpolator { val trees: Trees.this.type } = new {
      protected val trees: Trees.this.type = Trees.this
     } with Interpolator    

     ...
}
```

In summary, the whole snippet does not make much sense to me (and it is a pattern frequently repeated in the code), let me explain:

1. What is this syntax?

`val interpolator: Interpolator { ... }`

up to now I wrote `val name: Type = value`, here there is no equal.

2. `Trees.this.type` should be a type, but what type? It should be defined in Trees trait, and the `this` context which I bet is different from the `trait Trees` context (related to problem 1). I also looked on file [Interpolators](https://github.com/epfl-lara/inox/blob/75d81143a4a53ae138fdb34254e1928316dd0d19/src/main/scala/inox/parsing/Interpolator.scala) but there does not seem to be a type element.
3. The greatest line is `protected val trees: Trees.this.type = Trees.this`.

Can anybody explain me what is going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. It's a declaration of variable `interpolator` with type `Interpolator { val trees: Trees.this.type }`. The type `Interpolator { val trees: Trees.this.type }` is a subtype of `Interpolator`, but [refined](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/03-types.html#compound-types) with the additional restriction that `trees` is not just some `Trees`, but instead one concrete instance of `Trees`, namely the one of the singleton type `Trees.this.type`. There is an equal-`=`-symbol: between the type `Interpolator { val trees: Trees.this.type }` and the `new { ... } with Interpolator`.

   Shorter example which demonstrates the syntax in isolation:

   ```
   trait Foo {
     val trees: Any
   }
   def interpolator: Foo { val trees: Int } = 
     new Foo { val trees = 42 }

   interpolator.trees + 58
   ```
2. `Trees.this.type` is the [singleton type](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/03-types.html#singleton-types) of the value `this`. There is only one value of this type: `Trees.this`.

   Shorter example that demonstrates usage of `.type`:

   ```
   class Bar
   val b = new Bar
   val c: b.type = b
   ```
3. You are setting the value `trees` to `Trees.this`. You also guarantee to the compiler that `trees` is not just some `Trees`, but that `trees` is the singleton value `Trees.this` of the singleton type `Trees.this.type`, which is a strict subtype of `Trees`.

Comment: I noted a typo in Thees.this.type (Thees -> Trees). Is this then some kind of singleton pattern for traits? In other words, what is the effect of the three pieces together?

Comment: @Rodrigo It's just the `Interpolator` promising to every other subcomponent of `Trees` that whenever it refers to `val trees`, it means `Trees.this` of type `Trees.this.type`. There's really nothing more to it.